# Angular Bootstrap Carousel - Only slides first

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an angular application and cannot implement Angular Bootstrap Carousel. It works, but changes first slide, but stop the animation on second slide.

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <carousel interval="200">
        <slide ng-repeat="msg in messages track by $index" index="$index">
          <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 20px;"><i class="icon ion-quote textoAzul"></i></p>
          <h2 style="text-align: left; width: 100%; white-space: normal;"><|msg|></h2>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
</div>
```

JS on the controller:

```
  $scope.slideSpeed = 200;
  $scope.messages = [];
  $scope.messages[0] = "Msg 1";
  $scope.messages[1] = "Msg 2";
  $scope.messages[2] = "Msg 3";
  $scope.messages[3] = "Msg 4";
  $scope.messages[4] = "Msg 5";
```

Whats the problem?? Why I cant see third slide??

Comment: have you checked the developer's console ? Any Errors ?

Comment: Any errors, empty console.